# Why do I get this error when I'm trying to create models from database?

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-core, entity-framework-core

I'm trying to create models from my Oracle database 10g using Entity Framework Core 5 `dbcontext scaffold`:

```
dotnet ef dbcontext scaffold "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=mssrv.infofer.local)(PORT=1533)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVICE_NAME=medusa)));User ID=TRAFICALERT_EFC;Password=traficalert" Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore -o Entities -f
```

However, I got the following error:

```
2021-05-05 08:21:12.783360 ThreadID:1   (ERROR)   OracleDatabaseModelFactory.Cre
ate() :  Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleException (0x80004005): ORA-00904
: "DEFAULT_COLLATION": invalid identifier
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleConnectionImpl.VerifyExecution(Int32&
cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors, SqlStatementType sqlStatementTyp
e, Int32 arrayBindCount, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& has
MoreRowsInDB, Boolean bFirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.VerifyExecution(OracleConn
ectionImpl connectionImpl, Int32& cursorId, Boolean bThrowArrayBindRelatedErrors
, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, Boolean& hasMoreRowsInDB, Boolean b
FirstIterationDone)
   at OracleInternal.ServiceObjects.OracleCommandImpl.ExecuteReader(String comma
ndText, OracleParameterCollection paramColl, CommandType commandType, OracleConn
ectionImpl connectionImpl, OracleDataReaderImpl& rdrImpl, Int32 longFetchSize, I
nt64 clientInitialLOBFS, OracleDependencyImpl orclDependencyImpl, Int64[] scnFor
Execution, Int64[]& scnFromExecution, OracleParameterCollection& bindByPositionP
aramColl, Boolean& bBindParamPresent, Int64& internalInitialLOBFS, Int64 interna
lInitialJSONFS, OracleException& exceptionForArrayBindDML, OracleConnection conn
ection, OracleLogicalTransaction& oracleLogicalTransaction, IEnumerable`1 adrian
ParsedStmt, Boolean isDescribeOnly, Boolean isFromEF)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader(Boolean requer
y, Boolean fillRequest, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteReader()
   at Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleCommand.ExecuteScalar()
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.OracleDatabaseModelFactory
.<Create>g__GetCollation|9_0(DbConnection connection, String schema)
   at Oracle.EntityFrameworkCore.Scaffolding.Internal.OracleDatabaseModelFactory
.Create(DbConnection connection, IEnumerable`1 tables, IEnumerable`1 schemas)
```

Why do I get this error when I'm trying to create models from database?

Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [fine manual](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/?tabs=dotnet-core-cli) says minimum oracle 11.2  for that provider

[image]

Upgrade your db or change provider

Comment: My company doesn't want to upgrade the database. Also, I know about Devart but my company won't invest in this. Is it a good idea to get the DDL scripts and create a local Oracle database 11.2, then use it to create the models?

Comment: But they'll pay you to spend days of your life working round this hurdle only to hit more down the line, which they'll have to pay you more money to work around? All to save $159 dollars worth of license fee? Sounds like you need to find a job somewhere else, somewhere that has some grasp of business sense. If I were to set out to build a car, I wouldnt spend millions in making a factory that makes tyres. I'd just fit tyres that someone already made

Comment: That's a good point but now I need to find a solution. I don't see any other solution here so, I will use the DDL scripts to create a local database and then use scaffolding to create the models.

Comment: Using the free/trial version of Devart to prove whether it works for you might be a more valuable spend of time?

Comment: @littleO Reverse engineering could be just top of the iceberg. Not supported means it's not guaranteed to operate properly at runtime, so even if you overcome the current issue, you'll probably experience others (unresolvable) when trying to actually use EF Core to access the database. You'd better not experiment with that - either upgrade the database, either buy a provider which supports it, or use another ORM which supports it - EF Core is not for you.

Comment: You were right, @CaiusJard. To create the Models classes I have used Devart.Data.Oracle.EFCore, installed from NuGet Packages.